# jdkCompatibilityMode for OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, netty

The ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine configuration of jdkCompatibilityMode generally defaults to 'false'. Is there an API to configure it to 'true'? I'm interacting with a server (Azure SQL) that doesn't seem to like it as 'false'.

I'm using netty-4.1.49

---

Update:
Norman's recommendation works. I have adopted it, and eliminated my workaround. His is a more general solution which should preempt any other as-yet-undiscovered issues.

Answer (score 0):

That is strange as it should not matter for the remote peer and I would be interested to hear more detail about it.

That said you can force it by creating the `SSLEngine` first and then manually constructing the `SslHandler`.

```
SslContext context = ...
SSLEngine engine = context.newEngine(...);
SslHandler handler = new SslHandler(engine);
```

Comment: I would tend to agree with you, but in this specific case it was not so. At least at present, Azure SQL cannot tolerate an RPC message split across two TLS payloads if that RPC message is for an sp_executesql call. If it occurs, the server will immediately close the connection without reporting any errors. This was problematic if: 1) the message sent was embodied in a CompositeByteBuf with more than one component and 2) the handler did not have jdkCompatibilityMode set. I worked around it by using unwrap() and consolidate() to flatten the buffer.

Comment: This is definitly a bug in Azure SQL then as fragmentation can always happen.

Comment: Done, but I'm too much of a StackOverflow newb for to show up in the public stats